# installing latex on windows 10

Tags: windows-10, latex

How to install Latex on Windows 10.  I downloaded http://mirror.ctan.org/systems/texlive/tlnet/install-tl-windows.exe this 18 mb file and just double clicked on it. It started installing

```
Installing to: C:/texlive/2019
Installing [0001/3966, time/total: ??:??/??:??]: texlive.infra [416k]
Installing [0002/3966, time/total: 00:07/15:09:12]: texlive.infra.win32 [1395k]

Installing [1092/3966, time/total: 01:29:41/05:30:31]: dviljk.win32 [45k]
Installing [1093/3966, time/total: 01:30:25/05:33:12]: dviout-util [39k]
Installing [1094/3966, time/total: 01:30:48/05:34:36]: dviout-util.win32 [88k]
Installing [1095/3966, time/total: 01:31:06/05:35:41]: dviout.win32 [2183k]
```

and 
after some time it gets stuck

```
TLUtils::check_file: checksums differ for C:\Users\Debian\AppData\Local\Temp\rUZv0haGA6\WhWljBRB_5/dviout.win32.tar.xz:
TLUtils::check_file:   tlchecksum=0bb4d4d733246abbec583e6ba6528a650a7ab7d597779bac0a8860655427f7b14539549b11b32324d1dc94fc175f7021e1f44a6ef405682dc5e6b4a260c14d9d, arg=0eab55d73cdd6b9ea7f06286ecd9d815958e97b2510fdac40a1efadae3b5bdb91f88340173e2a69fa0761e0048b349e05d3416dd6e1118548211e942e24b1983
Use of uninitialized value $check_file_tmpdir in concatenation (.) or string at C:/Users/Debian/AppData/Local/Temp/nsbF045.tmp/install-tl-20191122/tlpkg/TeXLive/TLUtils.pm line 2187, <STDIN> line 106.
TLUtils::check_file:   removing C:\Users\Debian\AppData\Local\Temp\rUZv0haGA6\WhWljBRB_5/dviout.win32.tar.xz, but saving copy in 
Use of uninitialized value $destdir in concatenation (.) or string at C:/Users/Debian/AppData/Local/Temp/nsbF045.tmp/install-tl-20191122/tlpkg/TeXLive/TLUtils.pm line 1167, <STDIN> line 106.
Use of uninitialized value $destdir in -d at C:/Users/Debian/AppData/Local/Temp/nsbF045.tmp/install-tl-20191122/tlpkg/TeXLive/TLUtils.pm line 1170, <STDIN> line 106.
Use of uninitialized value $tree in string at C:/Users/Debian/AppData/Local/Temp/nsbF045.tmp/install-tl-20191122/tlpkg/TeXLive/TLUtils.pm line 889, <STDIN> line 106.
Use of uninitialized value $tree in substitution (s///) at C:/Users/Debian/AppData/Local/Temp/nsbF045.tmp/install-tl-20191122/tlpkg/TeXLive/TLUtils.pm line 895, <STDIN> line 106.
Use of uninitialized value $tree in split at C:/Users/Debian/AppData/Local/Temp/nsbF045.tmp/install-tl-20191122/tlpkg/TeXLive/TLUtils.pm line 897, <STDIN> line 106.
open(>/dviout.win32.tar.xz) failed: Permission denied at C:/Users/Debian/AppData/Local/Temp/nsbF045.tmp/install-tl-20191122/tlpkg/TeXLive/TLUtils.pm line 1204, <STDIN> line 106.
cannot unlink file for C:\Users\Debian\AppData\Local\Temp\rUZv0haGA6\WhWljBRB_5\dviout.win32.tar.xz: Permission denied at C:\Users\Debian\AppData\Local\Temp\nsbF045.tmp\install-tl-20191122\tlpkg\tlperl\lib/File/Temp.pm line 784.
cannot remove directory for C:\Users\Debian\AppData\Local\Temp\rUZv0haGA6\WhWljBRB_5: Directory not empty at C:\Users\Debian\AppData\Local\Temp\nsbF045.tmp\install-tl-20191122\tlpkg\tlperl\lib/File/Temp.pm line 784.
cannot remove directory for C:/Users/Debian/AppData/Local/Temp/rUZv0haGA6: Directory not empty at C:\Users\Debian\AppData\Local\Temp\nsbF045.tmp\install-tl-20191122\tlpkg\tlperl\lib/File/Temp.pm line 784.
cannot unlink file for C:\Users\Debian\AppData\Local\Temp\rUZv0haGA6\WhWljBRB_5\dviout.win32.tar.xz: Permission denied at C:\Users\Debian\AppData\Local\Temp\nsbF045.tmp\install-tl-20191122\tlpkg\tlperl\lib/File/Temp.pm line 784.
cannot remove directory for C:/Users/Debian/AppData/Local/Temp/rUZv0haGA6/WhWljBRB_5: Directory not empty at C:\Users\Debian\AppData\Local\Temp\nsbF045.tmp\install-tl-20191122\tlpkg\tlperl\lib/File/Temp.pm line 784.
```

What should I do now so that installation happens complete?

Answer (score 0):

0) Clean house. Delete the destination directory from the original attempt and everything in it, and delete the original downloaded installer file.

1) Go to http://ctan.math.utah.edu/ctan/tex-archive/systems/texlive/tlnet/ and get the checksum for the installer *install-tl-windows.exe.sha512*

2) Download the installer file again.

3) When the download completes, before you start installation, verify it downloaded OK by running a SHA512 checksum on the newly downloaded installer, with the command `certutil -hashfile c:\Users\Yourusername\Downloads\install-tl-windows.exe  SHA512`

4) Compare it to the checksum file you got in step 2. If it matches, then you can install with it.

Comment: I downloaded 2 files on from that link one is `install-tl-windows.exe` and another was `install-tl-windows.exe.sha512` now I did go inside the downloaded folder
`C:\Users\Debian\softwares\latex>certutil.exe -hashfile install-tl-windows.exe.sha512 SHA512
SHA512 hash of install-tl-windows.exe.sha512:
a633ea2bed732f42f942e532a2935805e93405834a710cbe3b81149f9e740a55b63b621a95cb1bbb32a399ab1138889c7c0a90435e602c85089190a46017d632
CertUtil: -hashfile command completed successfully.` I think this checked the hash of `install-tl-windows.exe.sha512` but I think I should have checked the hash of

Comment: the file install-tl-windows.exe on the download link got downloaded as `install-tl-windows_2.exe`  so I did now `C:\Users\Debian\softwares\latex>certutil.exe -hashfile install-tl-windows_2.exe SHA512
SHA512 hash of install-tl-windows_2.exe:
ab9298b865472fbd0d7630849a624cf4a09ba625371c6845937400bd94b7fd05a10bebdf5295d5e6cb4242fd1b4bdc76e52a3cca72a4440e3ff7bb068f9b68fa
CertUtil: -hashfile command completed successfully.`
I have deleted previous files and all installation follders.